# How add hyperlinks to eCommerce web page in Odoo ? How add field from another model inside of a XML?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-website

I want the add hyperlinks for every product on my eCommerce website in Odoo. Every product will have unique hyperlinks.
I thought of creating a variable somewhere and using them in the

`web-sale -> views -> templates_view.xml` but i couldn't made it.

How can I use a variable from a different module inside XML?

```
<p t-if="True" class="css_not_available_msg alert alert-warning">This combination
does not exist.
</p>
<h1 t-field="product.qty_available"/>
<div id="add_to_cart_wrap" class="d-inline">
<a role="button" id="add_to_cart"
   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg js_check_product a-submit my-1 mr-1 px-5 font-weight-bold flex-grow-1"
   href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-2"/>ADD TO CART
</a>
<div id="product_option_block" class="d-inline-block align-middle"/>
</div>
```

for example, I have an app with the name "TEST_APP" and a module with

```
name = "test"
```

and it has a field

```
test_bool = fields.Boolean(string="Test field")
```

Field in different module and XML in the web-sale module.

How can I use this field inside of this XML?

Sorry, I ask a lot of questions but I think I should learn this first for a solution.

Maybe after I can add links for every product on the eCommerce web site.

Comment: Did you try `<website_url>/shop/product/<product_id>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to review [Odoo documentation on how to extend templates](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/website.html?highlight=inherit_id#altering-existing-views) :)

What you want is to inherit from `website_sale.product` and do some xpaths to place yourself in the template. e.x. if you want to add your boolean test_bool and have that boolean on product, not another model, if it's to add it on a product...

So, some python and some xml. Don't forget to add website_sale in your depends key of your `__manifest__`.

Python (product model):

```py
from odoo import models, fields

class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    test_bool = fields.Boolean('Test Bool')
```

XML (inherit the template and put test_bool above the button "add to cart")

```xml
<template id="product" inherit_id="website_sale.product">
    <xpath expr="//a[@id='add_to_cart']" position="before">
        <span t-esc="product.test_bool"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Note: this will be ugly at this place :p

Hope it helped